# Error with storing IP Address

Tags: php, sql

I created a quick and easy Affiliate Referring script that would check the affiliate ID, if that was a registered ID it would then check the database for the IP that it came from, if it was not in the list it would award the affiliate 1 point.

However, when I checked the test version over 30 different IP addresses, not all of them have stored and it seems to have stopped saving them after a certain point.

The database is just a regular mysql one.

How would you go about storing an IP and awarding affiliates?

EDIT: Code

```
function awardAffiliate() {
global $wpdb;

//get the affliateID from the url. 
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$affiliateID = basename(parse_url($url,  PHP_URL_PATH));


//get the IP address. 
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
/


$checkAffiliate = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_count FROM affiliate_members WHERE user_id = '$affiliateID'"));

foreach ($checkAffiliate as $affiliate) { 

    $regAffiliateID = $affiliate->user_id;
    $regAffiliateCount = $affiliate->user_count;
}

// ammend them so that the count is +1 and the ip address is pushed into the array. add ',' before new ipaddress

$newCount = $regAffiliateCount + 1;


$updateffiliate = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE affiliate_members SET user_count = '$newCount' WHERE user_id = '$affiliateID'"));

$checkIpaddresses = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT affiliateID, source FROM affiliate_ip WHERE affiliateID = '$affiliateID'"));

foreach ($checkIpaddresses as $ipaddress) { 
    $ipSource = $ipaddress->source;
}


$addIP = "," .$ipAddress;
$ipSource .= $addIP;

$updateIpAddress = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE affiliate_ip SET source = '$ipSource' WHERE affiliateID = $affiliateID"));
```

}

Comment: how are you storing the ip address? string? long int? are you using `ip2long()`  php function? does your code handle both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses?

Comment: You appear to insert into `affiliate_ip` a list of coma-separated IP addresses. Is that what you intend? In any case, it's very hard to debug SQL from the source PHP. You should `var_dump()` your generated queries.

Comment: Yes that is what i intend. However Is that the best practice to store it, can someone help me with this? hopefully each id in the future would be storing potentially thousands of IP addresses.